# В связи - союз?

Tags: синтаксис, грамматика, морфология

Может ли **в связи** быть союзом? Напр.: «В связи с появившимися сложностями, сроки выполнения работы решили увеличить». Чем является здесь **"в связи"?**

На Грамоте.ру **в связи** - предлог. По мнению этого сайта [союз и предлог](http://yandex.ru/clck/jsredir?from=yandex.ru%3Bsearch%2F%3Bweb%3B%3B&text=&etext=1007.5S0O6RBfL78VLuPJno2BsujW_490Q5JL-Wh4csrn-fB-ZlfYO6TtlRkY2TzgMsCMh16AVc_5psL0B1IO7nklHk44BoeFj4Mw-XGShpnJYYA.4d4ab762c939dfaa9b6d67a4ff8e2db042e1827a&uuid=&state=PEtFfuTeVD5kpHnK9lio9ZA7Np24Z20t470I-vJO_GIiNhWIhYNH5g&data=UlNrNmk5WktYejR0eWJFYk1Ldmtxc09XZmt5N0NKVk1qVHNTeXZyRjdQbHNOdkw4LVFwNVloWi1xZ0Z0bU5FVTctRUpaQTBLTmVrRGwwOUJhUW10X3RXcThDZjJiSktYYkZwX0Jlb2oyb0hpMTEyNVB1ckJubGNQMmZKTVNfYlhsVmNOLTRGakpaZDR3RExaSExjTWRpY2RuLXN1dXdrR3BOVTRoblNObXNmTVFPMkhuMFpJMFNTT3hjaXBZVE44&b64e=2&sign=bdfa3d2c4ee7b31778ef75c1b331c143&keyno=0&cst=AiuY0DBWFJ5Hyx_fyvalFD3G1W6MyAkdlewxKNyKDpmXWuGWv5I0R4EYLx3RuL6g7LWMaKMl7XSsiuXnoi38jo4sCOxjbCmuJp5g6LxWS-W16qYLwybsnC6aFp5HvAHA3rtYcNGsmKgCFF0nNfBjuxybNmLPpfrISiZNsNTTCIPCPSajBDVNvMUklYNreSeDN4iyzIGmtssiBvUlIvwcpA&ref=orjY4mGPRjk5boDnW0uvlrrd71vZw9kp-hc71u5aWupnYDS-fJUDXnZdxPaATJir9HH6i9bzTbmNNnfSK6vpTYtUik1dBEqwDKJEaPJiq4cGtXee1Snokb6l066EESThLq0eWTUnkeJM922UCheeESOl7eZqi4X7pC3OwqvQcw3A_XJudM1oDtY912mpeL5EkbRTU1Vf_v7X64Tg38qGi_UMIs3oOEA5RpGgT8uqNRrQW6zUTQ5Mib-RgDAJxtntZGrOrTa3p1qlBsD1-e-egYJFgObTdmOZMaM8-K8LoUA&l10n=ru&cts=1459169286511&mc=4.917871728845195)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Предлог: В связи с появившимися сложностями, сроки выполнения работы решили увеличить».
2. Падежная форма "в связи" может входить в составные союзы причины и цели:  в связи с тем, чтобы;  в связи с тем, что.  Союз может расчленяться или не расчленяться.

Но в связи с тем, что Англия в тот период проводила довольно осторожную политику на Кавказе, поляки не смогли получить от англичан реальной поддержки.

Вероятно, такая традиция сложилась в связи с тем, чтобы не подрывать авторитета всех бывших, сущих и будущих капитанов; все капитаны априори мудры, толковы, смелы, добродетельны.

Comment: Это все я знаю. Мне нужны авторитетные источники.

Comment: А что Вы имеете в виду? Вот, к примеру, вузовская грамматика, где указаны эти составные  союзы, - это не авторитетный источник? В учебнике по морфологии рассматривается предлог "в связи с".

Comment: @Серж, у Розенталя "в связи с" - предлог : http://www.gumer.info/bibliotek_Buks/Linguist/rozent1/02.php  - как и в этой памятке для ЕГЭ, где приводится и союз "в связи с тем, что": http://4-5plus.ru/teorija/215-slushebnye.html

Comment: Издания авторитетные, но вы не сослались на них в своем ответе.

Comment: Да, Александр, спасибо. Заглянул в Русскую грамматику. Там написано, что  союз ''в связи с тем, что" образован из первообразного предлога.